# What kernel do I have to download for Nexus 6p?

Tags: android, kernel

I am trying to work on the kernel of Nexus6P (either of angler or bullhead).
But here in a google git page:

```
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/
```

I cannot find any release branch for angler and bullhead.

Am I seeing the page that is not correct, or can I just work on dr or mr versions (which I have already tried to build unsuccessfully)?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel actually is in the msm repository, however the "master" branch of that has not been updated in several years.  You will need to check out an appropriate recent branch, perhaps one of the ones with "angler" in the name (reflecting your device) or else one of the latest versions such as an N preview.

Then, because this is a 64 bit target, the defconfig for angler will be found in /arch/arm64/configs rather than the plain arm directory - the Makefile should pick it up regardless, but if you are looking for it manually you will need to look in the right place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Actually, I tried the branch "android / kernel / msm / android-msm-angler-3.10-marshmallow-mr1", but "make angler_defconfig" does not look alright with this branch: I see some warning with "make angler_defconfig" and eventually got an error when building. So I was wondering if this branch has a known issue, and I need to use a different one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reply to the comment for the answer below. Feel free to move it there.

Just set the following env variables. it will fetch the right defconfig , right now , its looking at the arch/arm folder , instead it should look at arch/arm64

```
$ export ARCH=arm64 
$ export SUBARCH=arm64
```